# How to change the font of a form created in typo3 8.7?

Tags: css, typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

Im absolutely new to typo3 and want to set up a simple contact form. So I created a form and added it to the page. My template record looks like this:

```
page = PAGE
page.typeNum = 0
page.10 < styles.content.get
page.includeCSS {
  file1 = fileadmin/templates/css/style.css
}
```

I can see the form and it works appropriately, but unfortunately my css doesnt do anything.

My style.css looks like this:

```
p {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 120px;
}
```

Gotta admit i have no knowledge about CSS too. The changes I made had absolutely no impact on my page. Do these infos help you by any chance? I just have no idea how to fix it on my own, been searching for a solution all day long.

Comment: Not sure if it's a copy/paste error here, but `page .10` should be `page.10` (without space). You also might want to add more information about what you see in the frontend. Do you see the form, but not the styling? Do you get an error? Do you get nothing?

Comment: maybe a cache problem?

Comment: @rudyGnodde yeh copy/paste error.

Answer (score 1):

you should learn more about the structure of CSS-files. maybe you inspect some with your browser from other sites.

Then you will notice it is something like:

```
p {
    font-family: arial; 
}
```

---

For file pathes in typoscript or objects and attributes: don't insert spaces:

```
:
page.10 < styles.content.get
page.includeCSS {
    file1 = fileadmin/templates/css/style.css
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. the spaces came up when i copied the code, didnt double check.

Answer (score 1):

Your `style.css` should only contain this:

```
p {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 120px;
}
```

... and you'll see the difference ;)

Probably only a copy&paste error, but your TypoScript (aka template record) has spaces where it shouldn't:

```
...
file1 = fileadmin/templates/css/style.css
...
```

Comment: did as suggested but i still cant see any difference unfortunately. edited the question though as the question is still unsolved.

Answer (score 1):

120px will result in a really big font ;-)

Set the style-definition to the body-tag (so for all elements below the body), not only for the p.

```
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define the styling of the input fields seperately. With some browsers the inheritance from the body tag definitions seem not to work.

input, textarea { font-size:1.25em; font-family:serif; border:1px solid darkgray; }

Something like that.